# php file_get_contents does not read jquery loads

Tags: php, jquery

In my continued efforts to make a simple crawler ...

I'm using file_get_contents but when a page has divs which are loaded via JQuery (the content of those divs depending on, say, the screen size) these pieces of content are ignored.

The page I'm crawling has a default window width in the Jquery code which is overridden if the script can pick up an actual window width.

file_get_contents is doing exactly what it says on the tin but is there an alternative way to get the Jquery loaded content for the default settings?

Comment: No javascript (jquery included) will run without some sort of engine. If you want your crawler to understand javascript, you are likely going to have to use something like `selenium`

Comment: You can also try  [**spidermonkey**](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey)

Comment: Well I've just realised that Google doesn't call this content either and has my crawler is SEO related ... if Google doesn't want it, neither does my crawler! Thanks for suggestions though.